# Do I have to process a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

When I call a function that returns a Promise do I have to use `.then()` on the promise.

ex. somefunc() returns a promise. Can I just do `somefunc();` or do I have to do

```
 somefunc().then( 
   function(){
   }, 
   function(){
   })
```

Similarly if I do use `.then()` do I have to specify both the `resolve` and `reject` functions or can I ignore the `reject`.
ex.

```
 somefunc().then( 
   function(){
   })
```

My concerns are possible memory etc. leaks.

Comment: Calling `.then()` should have no effect on the process. A Promise represents a result, not the process itself. As it happens, I was just watching the talk [Async Frontiers in JavaScript - Domenic Denicola](https://vimeo.com/132786072) which has a very interesting discussion of related design decisions.

Comment: You don't have to do anything, but if you want the result of the resolved promise, you have to chain on `then()`, which doesn't have a resolve and reject function, just a callback with the returned data as an argument, the error handler would be `catch()` !